# My wp-admin adminmenu css broken after insert 3 new post-types (wordpress 4.3)

Tags: css, wordpress

After create 3 new post-types in the adminmenu, the sidebar of the wp-admin hide some elements on hover and on active submenus, I try some changes in the height, display and position of the elements, but I don't where is the problem. See the image:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: what browser you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in Chrome and not a mistake you have made. It's being caused by something called "slimming paint" which is enabled by default.

> To disable this feature, visit chrome://flags/#disable-slimming-paint
>   in Chrome and Enable the Disable slimming paint option, and make sure
>   the other two Enable options are disabled because they will override
>   the Disable option. http://wptavern.com/a-bug-in-chrome-45-causes-wordpress-admin-menu-to-break

Answer (score 1):

This bug is in Chrome, Follow these solutions

Official Solution:

Disable slimmingPaint feature in chrome

```
1) In Chrome browser, navigate to: chrome://flags/#disable-slimming-paint (just enter the text into the address bar and hit enter)
2) You’ll see a list of technical options, with the “Disable slimming paint” option at the top; enable it
3) Disable the “Enable slimming paint” option if it’s enabled; just under the “Disable slimming paint” one
4) Relaunch Chrome
```

Other Solution:

If you or your clients don’t want to disable the Slimming Paint feature, then you can get around the bug by adding the following code into your theme functions.php file:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'chrome_adminmenu_fix');

function chrome_adminmenu_fix() {
    if ( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome' ) !== false )
        wp_add_inline_style( 'wp-admin', '#adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0); }' );
}
```